# I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable

Tags: java, android, animation, frame

I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frame_animation);

    // Directory creation and unzip file       
    DirCreation dc = new DirCreation();
    dc.creation();

    showedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);
    showedImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) showedImage.getBackground();
}
```

and also I am using external source sd card as image resource ...

I have used this file filename filter to fetch file from sd card and stored in string array

```
         FilenameFilter filefilter = new FilenameFilter() 
        {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
            {
            return (name.endsWith(".jpeg") || 
                    name.endsWith(".jpg") || 
                    name.endsWith(".png") );
            }
        };

        String[] sNamelist = pictureDirectory.list(filefilter);
        if (sNamelist.length == 0)
        {
            Log.d("Activity", "No pictures in directory.");
            return;
        }

        for (String filename : sNamelist) 
        {
            Log.d("Activity", pictureDirectory +  "/" +filename);

            frameAnimation.addFrame(
                    Drawable.createFromPath(pictureDirectory.getPath() +  "/" + filename), 210 );
        }

        return;
    }
```

picture directory is my path for sd card

```
pictureDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/animation/");
```

so, now what I have to do to set this images as my resource for frame animation...

Comment: post the full stack trace. I think showedImage.getBackground(); not returns the AnimationDrawable

Comment: post full src code of the file in which you are having exception.. ie how have you declare frameAnimations , and full Logcat

Comment: i have updated my code do have a look and suggest me some solution

Comment: kindly post your logcat error

Answer (score 0):

You need to have series of drawable objects defined in XML files to work with AnimationDrawable class. Example is as follows:

```
 <!-- Animation frames are wheel0.png -- wheel5.png files inside the
 res/drawable/ folder -->
 <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
 </animation-list>
```

As suggested by Amith, showedImage.getBackground(); returns a Drawable object.

Comment: but sir i am using sd card image resource